# Is there a class in JDK to represent an hour of the day, but not necessarily a specific hour at a specific date?

Tags: class, time, java, hour

Is there a class in JDK or Guava to represent an hour of the day, but not necessarily a specific hour at a specific date?
If not, why?

Comment: The usual answer on such questions is JODA-Time, I think.

Comment: It's called `short` ;) Well, ok `byte` might work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JDK 1.3-1.7, the answer is no. A specific time within a day is much easier to calculate then date, because you don't have to deal with leap year, leap month, such headache stuff. A simple integer is just enough. When you need to convert the time to a locale string, using SimpleDateFormatter or whatever, you can simply convert the time to a Date, just ignore the date part:

```
int time = 8 * 60 + 34; // 8:34 am
Date date = new Date(60000L * time);
```

Reset the time zone to +0, and pass the date to the formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply wrap a `byte` into a class and every time that the current hour passes 23 within your `increment()` (or appropriate name) method, set the value of the `byte` to 0, and whenever the value passes below 0 in your `decrement()` (or appropriate name) method, set the value of the `byte` to 23.

Comment: Well yeah i might create my own class for this and implement some useful methods. It is kinda boring to do such a common task, however. It's already the second time in a few months that i need this class.

Comment: It won't take too much.
Feel free to come back and ask questions if need be.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not a specific class representing `Hour` (in the JDK or Guava), but there are easy to use classes to fetch the hours from a specific instance of time (which is what I am assuming you are after with this question).

You could use JODA-Time, as Paŭlo Ebermann mentions, but that is an external library.  Within the JDK, there is a class called `Calendar`, which has many useful methods.

To get the hour of a `long` representing the current time, you could do this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR); //returns 0-11
int hourOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //returns 0-23
```